Load Balancer is not routing to Elastic Beanstalk host header
I want to deploy elastic beanstalk with load balanced type, connected to a shared load balancer. The application works fine using the elastic beanstalk dns endpoint. But I get Error 503 when i use the load balancer's dns endpoint to browse the elastic beanstalk application's web page.
I noticed this error is resolved if i change the default host header rule in the load balancer, from the EB dns endpoint to *.*. But i would like to be more specific with the host header as I am planning to connect two elastic beanstalk environments to the same load balancer.
Is there a way to figure out the proper host header that should be used?
Thanks
I tried to change the host header to the dns endpoint, but didnt work.
